# Robolectric unit tests fail with the same message using Exacttarget:4.0.4

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

This does not happen if I use any 3.5.x version, but it occurs on every 4.x version. Proguard changes have been made according to https://goo.gl/yMz3NL.

All unit tests fail with the following message -

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 231
   Exception Details:

> ```
>  Location:   com/exacttarget/etpushsdk/ETPushReceiver.onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V @28: new
>   Reason:
>     Expected stackmap frame at this location.
>   Bytecode:
>     0000000: 1218 1202 04bd 0022 5903 2ab6 0034 b600
>     0000010: 3253 b800 35b8 002f 57b8 002c bb00 1959
>     ... [removed 14 lines]                
>   Exception Handler Table:
>     bci [28, 228] => handler: 231
> ```

Comment: Can you please post the error from LogCat?  The only Proguard statement required can be found http://salesforcefuel.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/proguard.html  All of the documentation for 4.x+ has been moved to http://salesforcefuel.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/.  Please ensure you have followed the implementation instructions as 4.x is a significant departure from 3.x.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Mote. I've changed my Proguard file to include that statement only but that did not change anything. The app runs as expected, it's just that after I include SDK 4.0 or higher, it breaks all the robolectric unit tests in our app.

Comment: every unit test throws the same error -

"java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 231
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/exacttarget/etpushsdk/ETPushReceiver.onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V @28: new
      Reason:
        Expected stackmap frame at this location.
      Bytecode:
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved as of version 4.7.x of the SDK: [Release Notes](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/)

Please update to the latest version and, as always, please let us know if you're experiencing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue, you can fix the build by having

```
android {
    testOptions{
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
    }
}
```

in your build.gradle file, or if you're running from Android Studio/etc put '-noverify' in your VM Args for the run config

unfortunately after solving this issue I then get the following when Robolectric instantiates my custom Application class

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.m.c(SourceFile:263)
    at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.m.a(SourceFile:52)
    at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.EventBus.register(SourceFile:94)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not working when applying the solution to gradle.
But you can edit the configuration for test cases or test suite and provide "-noverify" as vm argument. Refer to attached image.[image]

Comment: Can you add a little more detail? At first glance, this almost looks like it might not even be an answer, though I do believe it is after rereading it.